# Counting number of Items that match a specified String in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I am trying to count the number of Items in a ListView that match "Reserved". I have the following code, but it's not counting properly.

```
public void update_seat(ListView lstv1, Label lbl1, Label lbl2)
{
   foreach (ListViewItem liv in lstv1.Items)
   {
      if (liv.SubItems[1].Text == "Reserved")
      {
         liv.Selected = true;

         int y = lstv1.SelectedItems.Count;
         lbl1.Text = y.ToString();

      }      
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are always assigning to `int y` in every iteration. You should increment the value instead. I'll give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the image below, the code below counts the number of occurences in a specified Column. You just need to adjust the integer in the `SubItems[int]` part.

```
public void update_seat(ListView lstv1, Label lbl1, Label lbl2)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach (ListViewItem item in lstv1.Items)
    {
            if (item.SubItems[0].Text == "Reserved")
                count++;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped :)If it solved your problem, or if you've solved the problem then please mark the appropriate answer as accepted. It helps others know what may work.